# Create a stacked 2D histogram using different weights

Tags: python, numpy, histogram

Say I want to build up histogram of particle data which is smoothed over some bin range, nbin. Now I have 5 data sets with particles of different mass (each set of x,y has a different mass). Ordinarily, a histogram of particle positions is a simple case (using numpy):

```
heatmap, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=nbin)
extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
heatmap = np.flipud(np.rot90(heatmap))
ax.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent)
```

However, if I want to add the next lot of particles, they have different masses and so the density will be different. Is there a way to weight the histogram by some constant such that the plotted heatmap will be a true representation of the density rather than just a binning of the total number of particles?

I know 'weights' is a feature, but is it a case of just setting weights = m_i where m_i is the mass of the particle for each dataset 1-5?

Comment: Yes, that should pretty much do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `weights` parameter expects an array of the same length as `x` and `y`. `np.histogram2d`. It will not broadcast a constant value, so even though the mass is the same for each call to `np.histogram2d`, you still must use something like

```
weights=np.ones_like(x)*mass
```

Now, one problem you may run into if you use `bin=nbin` is that the bin edges, `xedges`, `yedges` may change depending on the values of `x` and `y` that you pass to `np.histogram2d`. If you naively add heatmaps together, the final result will accumulate particle density in the wrong places.

So if you want to call `np.histogram2d` more than once and add partial heatmaps together, you must determine in advance where you want the bin edges.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as IT
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 50
nbin = 10

xs = [np.array([i,i,i+1,i+1]) for i in range(N)]
ys = [np.array([i,i+1,i,i+1]) for i in range(N)]
masses = np.arange(N)

heatmap = 0
xedges = np.linspace(0, N, nbin)
yedges = np.linspace(0, N, nbin)

for x, y, mass in IT.izip(xs, ys, masses):
    hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(
        x, y, bins=[xedges, yedges], weights=np.ones_like(x)*mass)
    heatmap += hist

extent = [xedges[0], xedges[-1], yedges[0], yedges[-1]]
heatmap = np.flipud(np.rot90(heatmap))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(heatmap, extent=extent, interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]